# How to apply string formatting to a bash command (incorporated into Python script via subprocess)?

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

I would like to add a bash command to my Python script, which linearises a FASTA sequence file while leaving sequence separation intact (hence the specific choice of command). Below is the command, with the example input file of "inputfile.txt":

```
awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);}  END {printf("\n");}' < inputfile.txt
```

The aim is to allow the user to specify the file which is to be modified in the command line, for example:

```
$ python3 program.py inputfile.txt
```

I have tried to use string formatting (i.e. `%s`) in conjunction with `sys.argv` in order to achieve this. However, I have tried many different locations of `"` and `'`, and still cannot get this to work and accept a user input from the command line here. 
(The command contains escapes such as `\n` and so I have tried to counteract this by adding additional backslashes, as well as additional `%` for the existing `%s` in the command.)

```
import sys
import subprocess

path = sys.argv[1]

holder = subprocess.Popen("""awk '/^>/ {printf("\\n%%s\\n",$0);next; } { printf("%%s",$0);}  END {printf("\\n");}' < %s""" % path , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

print(holder)
```

I would very much appreciate any help with identifying the syntax error here, or suggestions for how I could add this user input.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to implement that transformation in Python instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Don't shell out to awk! Just use Python. But let's go step by step...

---

Your instinct of using triple quotes here is good, then at least you don't need to escape both single and double quotes, that you need in your shell string.

The next useful device you can use is raw strings, using `r'...'` or `r"..."` or `r"""..."""`. Raw strings don't expand backslash escapes, so in that case you can leave the `\n`s intact.

Last is the `%s`, which you need to escape if you use the `%` operator, but here I'm going to suggest that instead of using the shell to redirect input, just use Python's subprocess to send stdin from the file! Much simpler and you end up with no substitution.

I'll also recommend that you use `subprocess.check_output()` instead of `Popen()`. It's much simpler to use and it's a lot more robust, since it will check that the command exited successfully (with a zero exit status.)

Putting it all together (so far), you get:

```
with open(path) as inputfile:
    holder = subprocess.check_output(
        r"""awk '/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);}  END {printf("\n");}'""",
        shell=True,
        stdin=inputfile)
```

But here you can go one step further, since you don't really need a shell anymore, it's only being used to split the command line into two arguments, so just do this split in Python (it's almost always possible and easy to do this and it's a lot more robust since you don't have to deal with the shell's word splitting!)

```
with open(path) as inputfile:
    holder = subprocess.check_output(
        ['awk', r'/^>/ {printf("\n%s\n",$0);next; } { printf("%s",$0);}  END {printf("\n");}'],
        stdin=inputfile)
```

The second string in the list is still a raw string, since you want to preserve the bacsklash escapes.

I could go into how you can do this without using `printf()` in awk, using `print` instead, which should get rid of both `\n`s and `%`s, but instead I'll tell you that it's much easier to do what you're doing in Python directly!

In fact, everything that awk (or sed, tr, cut, etc.) can do, Python can do better (or, at least, in a more readable and maintainable way.)

In the case of your particular code:

```
with open(path) as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            # Insert a blank line before this one.
            print()
        print(line)
        if line.startswith('>'):
            # Also insert a blank line after this.
            print()
    # And a blank line at the end.
    print()
```

Isn't this better?

And you can put this into a function, into a module, and reuse it anywhere you'd like. It's easy to store the result in a string, save it into a variable if you like, much more flexible...

Anyways, if you still want to stick to shelling out, see my previous code, I think that's the best you can do while still shelling out, without significantly changing the external command.